# How to deserialize JSON string received in controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have received JSON string received in controller and I am unable to deserialize it. Please help.
I have attached jquery code and controller method in which JSON string is received.
Json received : "[\"account2\",\"account1\"][\"BCS\"][\"Yes\"]"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kgit.png)

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function ()
        {
            alert(j + " " + k);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/TodoList/searchdata',
                traditional: true,
                dataType:"json",
                data: "myArray1="+JSON.stringify(i) +JSON.stringify(j)+JSON.stringify(k),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })

        });
```

### Controller code:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult searchdata(string myArray1)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(myArray1);
           // Console.WriteLine(myArray2);
            JavaScriptSerializer jsr=new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = jsr.Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(myArray1);
           Console.WriteLine(data);
            //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
            //{
            //    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //    connection.Open();
            //    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            //    String str= "select accntname,BU,salesop,isdormant from fourth_page as fg"+
            //                      " INNER JOIN linked as ld on ld.productid=fg.productid"+
            //                       "INNER JOIN isdormant as it on it.productid=ld.productid"+
            //                       "where fg.accountname in(" + values+")";
            //    cmd.CommandText = str;
            //    SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            //    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            //    {
            //        Console.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString() + "" + dr[1].ToString() + "" + Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]) + "" + Convert.ToBoolean(dr[3]));
            //    }               

            //    connection.Close();
            //}
            return Json(myArray1);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll either want to have the controller receive an object instead of a string and pass

```
{ 'firstField': i,
  'secondField': j,
  'thirdField': k
}
```

or try controller signature of

```
public JsonResult searchdata(List<string> firstField, List<string> secondField, List<string> thirdField)
```

and call by appending the following to the URL with a GET instead of an AJAX post

```
"?firstField=" + JSON.stringify(i) + "&secondField=" + JSON.stringify(j) + "&thirdField=" + JSON.stringify(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a JSON.
I believe you double serialize / encode it :).

Comment: Ok. I followed the link it is showing as error. what might be the possible solution. I have edited my question by appending code. Please help.